# MS Access returning empty recordset through Java code

Tags: java, ms-access

I am trying to retrieve results of a simple query to check if my connection is working or not. The connection is successful but there is only empty recordset returned. The problematic line is marked by a comment

Below is my code

```
             package ActualProject;
             import java.io.FileInputStream;
             import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
             import java.io.IOException;
             import java.sql.*;

             import net.ucanaccess.jdbc.*;
             import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
             import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
             import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

             public class MainClass {
             static String strURL = null;
             public MainClass() {
                        }

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String strUserDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    String strProjectPath = strUserDir.replaceAll("ActualProject", "");
    String strDataPath = strProjectPath + "Data\\Data.xlsx";
    String TestCaseDescription = null;
    String strTestCaseName = null;


    String TestCaseSheetPath = strProjectPath + "ActualProject\\TestCaseSheet\\TestCaseSheet.mdb";

    //Code to read TestCaseSheet
    try
    {
         Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");


        System.setProperty("DUCANACCESS_HOME","C:/Users/mindurka/
        Downloads/Selenium3.4/UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin/UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin");

         String connURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+TestCaseSheetPath;
         Connection objAccessCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);
         DriverManager.getConnection(connURL1);
         Statement objRS = objAccessCon.createStatement();

    //           String strEnvQuery = "Select * from Env where Use = 'No'";
         String strEnvQuery = "Select * from Env";
         objRS.executeQuery(strEnvQuery);
         ResultSet objEnvRS = objRS.getResultSet();


         while(objEnvRS.next())
         {
             strURL = objEnvRS.getString("URL");
             String strQuery = "Select * from TestCaseSheet where Execute = 'Yes'";
             objRS.execute(strQuery);
             ResultSet RS = objRS.getResultSet();
             if(RS != null)
             {
                 while (RS.next()) 
                {
                     TestCaseDescription = RS.getString("TestCaseDescription");
                     strTestCaseName = RS.getString("TestCaseName");
                     FileInputStream objFIS = new FileInputStream(strDataPath);
                     XSSFWorkbook objDataWB = new XSSFWorkbook(objFIS);
                     Sheet objActiveSheet = objDataWB.getSheet("RegDetails");

                     for(int intRowCounter = 0 ; intRowCounter < objActiveSheet.getLastRowNum(); intRowCounter++)
                     {
                         Row objRow = objActiveSheet.getRow(intRowCounter);
                         for(int intColumnCounter = 0; intColumnCounter < objRow.getLastCellNum(); intColumnCounter++)
                         {
                             System.out.println("Row=="+ intRowCounter + "Column =="+ intColumnCounter);
                         }
                     }

                     objActiveSheet= null;
                     //objRow = null;
                    objRS.close();
                    RS.close();
                    objAccessCon.close();

                }
             }
             else
             {
                 System.out.println("No testcases selected for execution");
             }




        }


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{

    }


}

}
```

Java version: 8
Eclipse version: Neon
MS Access version: 2007

Please let me know if any other details are required.
Edited comment: Adding the screenshot of the file[MSAccessScreenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBFLR.jpg)

Comment: What happen if you run the query directly in Access?

Comment: Are you sure _Execute_ contains literal 'Yes'? It should be True/False.

Comment: As Gustav says, if Execute is a Yes/No type field, the parameter should be `True` without apostrophes.

Comment: Yes. Please refer the newly added screenshot.

Comment: I am not even getting the recordset of a simple query  'Select * from Env'. Hence I cannot reach to the point you are referring to.

Comment: Posted the complete code now. Apologies for the messy code before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The createStatement was not working hence tried using PrepareStatement as below.

```
try
    {
         Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
         System.setProperty("DUCANACCESS_HOME","C:/Users/mindurka/Downloads
         /Selenium3.4/UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin/UCanAccess-4.0.2-bin");

         String connURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://"+TestCaseSheetPath;
         Connection objAccessCon = DriverManager.getConnection(connURL);

         String strEnvQuery = "Select * from Env where Use = 'Yes'";

         PreparedStatement pst = objAccessCon.prepareStatement(strEnvQuery);

         ResultSet objEnvRS = pst.executeQuery();


         //ResultSet objEnvRS = pst.getResultSet();

         Statement objRS = objAccessCon.createStatement();
         while(objEnvRS.next() == true) //shows true for objEnvRS.next() == true
         {strURL = objEnvRS.getString("URL");
         }
```

I have a newer problem. While the watch variable 'objEnvRS.getString("URL")' shows the correct value, programmatically my code doesn't go inside the while loop. Is there some sort of resultset/connection property I need to set to loop through the resultset?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to my later issue. I was trying to browse through the recordset with objEnvRS.next() in the watcvh section. This was causing the pointer to move one step ahead of required recordset row at the while loop. Will always remember to clear the watch section before executing/debugging any code hereafter. :)